# Can I have multiple DKIM txt records in single domain?

Tags: dkim

I have several cloud applications that send email. Each application has DKIM set up.

For example:

```
cloud app 1 : k=rsa; t=s; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDfl0chtL4siFYCrSPxw43fqc4zOo3N+Il220oK2Cp+NZw9Kuvg8iu2Ua3zfbUnZWvWK4aEeooliRd7SXIhKpXkgkwnAB3DGAQ6+/7UVXf9xOeupr1DqtNwKt/NngC7ZIZyNRPx1HWKleP13UXCD8macUEbbcBhthrnETKoCg8wOwIDAQAB
cloud app 2 : k=rsa; t=s; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDfl0chtL4siFYCrSPxw43fqc4zOo3N+Il220oK2Cp+NZw9Kuvg8iu2Ua3zfbUnZWvWK4aEeooliRd7SXIhKpXkgkwnAB3DGAQ6+/7UVXf9xOeupr1DqtNwKt/NngC7ZIZyNRPx1HWKleP13UXCD8macUEbbcBhthrnETKoCg8wOwIDAQAB
```

**Can I add two separate `TXT` records to my DNS? Or should I combine both `TXT` records into one?**

Please explain how to add multiple `TXT` records for a single domain.

Answer (score 43):

Yes you can.
A DKIM signature looks like this:

```
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=example.com;
 s=selector1; h=From:Date:Subject:Message-ID:Content-Type:MIME-Version;
 bh=M1X/nttSCpN...ttSCpN=;
 b=SPso8U12ChySEQcnJcvm76...RAxjJFcBI=
```

During validation the selector and domain (selector1 and example.com above respectively) are both used to locate the TXT record with the public key. This is done by merging them with _domainkey in between:

```
selector1._domainkey.example.com
```

In your case you can use 2 different selectors (like cloudapp1 and cloudapp2), then each private key can have its own unique DNS record. The corresponding DNS entries would look something like:

```
cloudapp1._domainkey 3600 IN TXT "v=DKIM1; k=rsa; t=s; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDfl0chtL4siFYCrSPxw43fqc4zOo3N+Il220oK2Cp+NZw9Kuvg8iu2Ua3zfbUnZWvWK4aEeooliRd7SXIhKpXkgkwnAB3DGAQ6+/7UVXf9xOeupr1DqtNwKt/NngC7ZIZyNRPx1HWKleP13UXCD8macUEbbcBhthrnETKoCg8wOwIDAQAB"
cloudapp2._domainkey 3600 IN TXT "v=DKIM1; k=rsa; t=s; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDfl0chtL4siFYCrSPxw43fqc4zOo3N+Il220oK2Cp+NZw9Kuvg8iu2Ua3zfbUnZWvWK4aEeooliRd7SXIhKpXkgkwnAB3DGAQ6+/7UVXf9xOeupr1DqtNwKt/NngC7ZIZyNRPx1HWKleP13UXCD8macUEbbcBhthrnETKoCg8wOwIDAQAB"
```

Answer (score 20):

Yes, you can have multiple DKIM records, TXT or CNAME-typed, on a single domain.

Multiple DKIM selectors and private/public key pairs are usually created for these reasons:

1 a domain uses multiple email delivery services to send emails, in which case, multiple DKIM selectors and private/public key pairs must be used to separate these services.

For example, if you authorize both Mailchimp and Convertkit to send emails on behalf of you, you need to have at least (usually more) 1 for Mailchimp and 1 for Convertkit. This way, the signing/verification servers can locate the correct key pairs.

2 even you are using only one email delivery service, having multiple selectors/key pairs is a best practice due to security reasons. One needs to periodically change the key pairs to lower the risk of being compromised. This is known as “DKIM key rotation”.

When you create multiple DKIM records, you need to choose a selector that is unique across all DKIM records on that domain. This way, the use of a DKIM record doesn't interfere with that of another.

Refer to this post for more information: https://dmarcly.com/blog/what-is-dkim-selector-and-how-does-it-work-dkim-selector-explained

Answer (score 14):

Yes, you should have multiple `TXT` records, and you keep them separate by using `DKIM selectors`.

Read the following link for more information https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215029758

Comment: Could you please give me an example? (which selector)

Comment: @ManicDepression - The DNS TXT record: "myselector._domainkey" added to your domains DNS -> The "myselector" portion is made up by you and must be unique. So asking 'which selector' makes no sense.